What is the proper mowing height for a turf lawn in Northern Illinois to crowd out weeds?
first-time poster in need of help.
This and last year I've taken the approach of crowding out weeds and pulling by hand instead of using weed killers. This is partially because we have a dog that thinks she's a cow and loves to graze on occasion and also because I don't want the chemicals associated with 'weed & feed' solutions ending up in our local water supply. While I go down to about three inches with each mowing, I'm wondering if I should let the grass grow taller or just cut everything shorter to help stop the spread of weeks.
I'm in northern Illinois, and there's crabgrass, yarrow, dandelions, white clover, and this weed that has small yellow flowers on it all throughout the lawn. They aren't overtaking the yard - yet - but I'm not trying to have a clover based yard, I prefer grass. Alternatively, if mowing height won't greatly impact weed spread, what are more natural (such as corn gluten pre-emergents) treatments I can apply that would help?
I subscribe to the Sunday lawn care service, and sent in a soil analysis last spring. Here are the results if it would be at all helpful in determining mowing height:
Soil Profile: 66% silt, 20% sand, 14% clay



Element Tested
Value




Organic Matter
3.2%


Soil PH
6.9


Cation exchange
6.9


Nitrogen release
82 lb/N/acre est.


Phosphorus
50 ppm


Potassium
126 ppm


Sulfur
7 ppm


Calcium
1397 ppm


Magnesium
314 ppm


Boron
0.54 ppm


Iron
185 ppm


Manganese
89 ppm


Zinc
14.9 ppm


Sodium
20 ppm



Thanks in advance for your help!
